# Mapping array in a Text component

Tags: arrays, react-native, split

I call an API and I receive a JSON response with a text that contain `<br />`

I do that to split my JSON with `<br />` tag and store it in an array:

```
render() {
...
var body = law.body;
const bodies = body.split('<br />');
this.setState({bodies: bodies});
...
}
```

then I try to map this array to put each value in a `Text` tag:

```
const bodyText = <View>
                    {this.state.bodies.map((data) => {
                        return(
                          <Text style={Styles.body}>
                            {data}
                          </Text>
                        );
                    })};
                </View>;
```

I don't know if my appraoch is correct or not but it doesn't work. I got this error: `...Text strings must be rendered within an <Text> component.`

here is the entire code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './Styles';
import Colors from '../../../config/colors';
import IconMI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import IconE from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';


class LawItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bodies: [],
    }
  }
  render() {
    const law = this.props.law
    var body = law.body;
    const bodies = body.split('<br />');
    this.setState({bodies: bodies});

    const bodyText = <View>
                        {this.state.bodies.map((data) => {
                            return(
                              <Text style={Styles.body}>
                                {data}
                              </Text>
                            );
                        })};
                    </View>;


    console.log('this is: ' + bodies);
    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
          <Text style={Styles.head}>
            {law.head}
          </Text>
          {bodyText}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LawItem
```

**PS. my code works without splitting JSON data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `setState` in your render function? That’s not good because you’ll cause infinite rerenders.

Also, `setState` is async, so it won’t be available for immediate use.

Instead compute `bodies` in your render function and use `bodies` like you are doing here, but only if if it changes constantly, or compute it once in a method like `componentDidMount` and set it to state and then use state.bodies from your render.

Let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I have change this.state.bodies.map()... with this.bodies.map()....  I got undefined is not an object

Comment: thank you it works fine, I will put the code in another response for other people

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code;

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './Styles';
import Colors from '../../../config/colors';
import IconMI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import IconE from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';


class LawItem extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const law = this.props.law
    var body = law.body;
    var bodies = body.split('<br />');

    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
          <Text style={Styles.head}>
            {law.head}
          </Text>

          { bodies.map((item, key)=>(
            <Text key={key} style={Styles.body}>
             { item }
            </Text>
          ))}


      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LawItem
```